# Server side Datatables not working with Classic ASP

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, datatables, server-side

I have a table with 120.000 record. I found an example for server-side pagination  in [this link](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) for listing my records. And I looked for a sample written in ASP and I found [it](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/asp_classic). But it is not working. If someone have working codes, can he/she send me a link?

My error code is:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response.

I found [this link](http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) for this error. But I didn't understand.

My script:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "musteri_list_load.asp"
   } );
 } );
```

And musteri_list_load.asp codes:

```
<%
'here we get some parameters passed by the DataTables using GET
sEcho = Cint(Request("sEcho"))
iDisplayLength = Cint(Request("iDisplayLength"))
iDisplayStart = Cint(Request("iDisplayStart"))
sSearch = Request("sSearch")

'SEARCH - here we make the Where clause that will be used in the SQL query.     You only put here the fields you want to search
strWhere = " WHERE engine LIKE '%" & sSearch & "%' OR "
strWhere = strWhere &  " browser LIKE '%" & sSearch & "%' OR "
strWhere = strWhere &  " platform LIKE '%" & sSearch & "%' OR "
strWhere = strWhere &  " version LIKE '%" & sSearch & "%' OR "
strWhere = strWhere &  " grade LIKE '%" & sSearch & "%'"

'ORDERING
'passes through all cols and first check if the column is sortable, if yes then construct
'the variable "order" that list in order the sequence of ordering
for k=0 to 4
    if Request("bSortable_" & k)="true" then
        order = order & Request("iSortCol_" & k) & " " & Request("sSortDir_" & k)
    end if
next
'here we replace the number corresponding the column position by the corresponding name of the column in the database
order = Replace(order,"0",", engine")
order = Replace(order,"1",", browser")
order = Replace(order,"2",", platform")
order = Replace(order,"3",", version")
order = Replace(order,"4",", grade")

'here we eliminate the first comma of the variable "order"
order = Right(order, Len(order)-1)

'here we create the variable "strOrderBy" that will be used in the SQL query
strOrderBy = "ORDER BY " & order

'here we create the connection with the database (I used Microsoft SQL Server 2008)
Set Session("objConn") = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SQL_SERVER;Initial     Catalog=DATABASE;User Id=USERNAME;Password=PASSWORD;"
Session("objConn").open strConnection

'here we create the SQL query using the variables "strWhere" and "strOrderBy"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM ajax " & strWhere & strOrderBy
Set rs = Session("objConn").Execute(SQL)

'here is counted how many records we have in the query using the search criterion and call this as "iTotalDisplayRecords"
iTotalDisplayRecords = 0
if rs.eof = false then
do while not rs.eof
    iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalDisplayRecords + 1
    rs.movenext
loop
rs.movefirst
end if

'here we just count how many records we have in the table, WITHOUT any     search criterion and call this as "iTotalRecords"

SQL2 = "SELECT count(*) FROM ajax"
Set rs2 = Session("objConn").Execute(SQL2)
iTotalRecords = rs2(0)
'here we begin to mount the ajax reponse
%>
{"sEcho": <%=sEcho%>, "iTotalRecords": <%=iTotalRecords%>,   iTotalDisplayRecords": <%=iTotalDisplayRecords%>, "aaData": [
<% 
i= 0
'PAGINATION
'First we move the recordset for the first record of the page that is being displayed in the table using the parameters(iDisplayStart)
'then we create a loop wich the limits are the parameters (iDisplayLength) or the end of the query

if rs.eof = false then

rs.move(iDisplayStart)

do while i < iDisplayLength and not rs.eof

        'we create the variable "aaData" that has the data that will be displayed. This variable is in a format known by the DataTable
        aaData = aaData + "['" & rs("engine") & "','" & rs("browser") & "','" & rs("platform") & "','" & rs("version") &  "','" & rs("grade") & "'],"
        'here we replace the single quotes by double quotes (chr(34))
        aaData = Replace(aaData,"'",chr(34))

        rs.movenext

        i=i+1

    loop
    'here we eliminate the last comma in the aaData
    aaData = Left(aaData,Len(aaData)-1)

else
    'if the query result has no records the aaData will be empty and the Table will give an answer that no record was find
    aaData = ""
end if

'here we finishes to mount the response
response.write aaData & "] }"
%>
```

My output data for musteri_list_load.asp:

```
{"sEcho": 0, "iTotalRecords": 33, "iTotalDisplayRecords": 20, "aaData": [ ] }
```

So, I don't get any data from database.

Comment: How isn't it working?  If you're getting an error message what is it?  That example must have worked in their own environment or they wouldn't have published it

Comment: Please visit `musteri_list_load.asp` and post the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looping through all records anyway, you could create the aaData in your first loop.

```
'here is counted how many records we have in the query using the search criterion and call this as "iTotalDisplayRecords"
iTotalDisplayRecords = 0
dim iFoundRecords : iFoundRecords = 0
aaData = ""
if rs.eof = false then
  do while not rs.eof
    iTotalDisplayRecords = iTotalDisplayRecords + 1
    if iTotalDisplayRecords >= iDisplayStart and iFoundRecords < iDisplayLength then 
      iFoundRecords = iFoundRecords + 1
      'we create the variable "aaData" that has the data that will be displayed. This variable is in a format known by the DataTable
      aaData = aaData + "['" & rs("engine") & "','" & rs("browser") & "','" & rs("platform") & "','" & rs("version") &  "','" & rs("grade") & "'],"
      'here we replace the single quotes by double quotes (chr(34))
      aaData = Replace(aaData,"'",chr(34))
    end if

    rs.movenext
  loop
  rs.movefirst
  if iFoundRecords > 0 then 
    'here we eliminate the last comma in the aaData
     aaData = Left(aaData,Len(aaData)-1)
  end if
end if
```

Otherwise you will need to check if rs.eof is true after the rs.movefirst.

Also on a general note, you should use prameterized queries. Currently your code is wide open for SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

an old post but the code above is a missing double quote preceding iTotalDisplayRecords, this is what causes the json error

{"sEcho": <%=sEcho%>, "iTotalRecords": <%=iTotalRecords%>,   "iTotalDisplayRecords": <%=iTotalDisplayRecords%>, "aaData": [